Moving forward from wordpress and php
Want to make a new website that is currently employing wordpress.  I am scrutinising other backend programming languages than php.  With a focus on free software, security, scalability and modern development practices.
My final analyses has been to use Kotlin.  I reached some conclusions.  Does it make sense?

For Scalability and Security: Java or Kotlin (especially with Spring Boot).
For Modern Development Practices: Kotlin (interoperability with Java while being more modern).
For Rapid Prototyping and Flexibility: Python (Django or Flask).
For Legacy System Compatibility: PHP (especially with CMS needs) or Perl (for existing Perl-based systems).
For Performance-Critical Systems: Rust (although rare for full backend systems).
